# Spring Cache - Generate custom cached result

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-cache

I'm using Spring Boot and EhCache to develop a calendar application.

Some users can request concerts for a specific week, others - for entire month. All responses are being cached with time to live 300 seconds to decrease the response time.

Input parameters for cached methods are `startDate`, `endDate` and a `username`.

The problem is when user requests concerts for the entire month, and then for a singe week within the same month, the method will be executed two times, even though the "week" response can be calculated based on the "month" response, since the week might be a subset of a cached month.

Examples:

```
1. 
INPUT
startDate:08.06.2016, endDate:07.07.2016, username:exampleUser
//the method is executed, response cached
OUTPUT
concert "Example Concert" on 13.06.2016
```

2.

```
INPUT
startDate:08.06.2016, endDate:15.06.2016, username:exampleUser
//the method is executed, response cached
OUTPUT
concert "Example Concert" on 13.06.2016
```

As you can see in the example, the method will be executed two times, but in fact it is not necessary to execute the method in second example, the response can be extracted from cached data returned in the first request.

I was thinking to create a custom "generator" for `concerts` cache which will be able to loop through all cached data and find date ranges that "contain" requested `startDate` and `endDate`

Here is what I have so far:

**Cached methods:**

```
@Override
    @CachePut("concerts")
    public List<Event> refreshEventsCache(String eventsForUser, Date startDate, Date endDate) throws Exception {

        return fetchEventsFromTheServer(eventsForUser, startDate, endDate);
    }


    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "concerts")
    public List<Event> getEvents(String eventsForUser, Date startDate, Date endDate) throws Exception {

        return fetchEventsFromTheServer(eventsForUser, startDate, endDate);
    }
```

**ehcache.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="500" eternal="false"
                  overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />

    <diskStore path="java.io.tempdir"/>

    <cache name="concerts"
           maxElementsInMemory="5000"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="0"
           timeToLiveSeconds="300"
           overflowToDisk="false"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
</ehcache>
```

**Application.java:**

```
...
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<SpringBootWebApplication> applicationClass = SpringBootWebApplication.class;



}
```

How can I build "smart" cache generator which will return subsets of cached data?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the Spring's Default Caching Mechanism here because in the following method,

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "concerts")
public List<Event> getEvents(String eventsForUser, Date startDate, Date endDate) throws Exception {

    return fetchEventsFromTheServer(eventsForUser, startDate, endDate);
}
```

Cache key will be generated based on all three parameters `eventsForUser, startDate, endDate`.

So in your second query which is a week falling in between the previous `startDate` and `endDate` the generated key will be different thus there will be a cache miss so it will load from database directly.

As you have requested, you need to implement a "Smart" Cache for this just an idea,

You can inject `CacheManager` and use it to retrieve the Cached List based on the cache key generated by you.

Ex:- Cache Key for startDate:08.06.2016, endDate:07.07.2016, username:exampleUser can be `08.06.2016_07.07.2016_exampleUser`.

You can use

```
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("08.06.2016_15.06.2016_exampleUser");
```

And Try to get the Week's cache first if it is a cache miss then you can go to the last date of the month of the `endDate` and check for Month's cache

```
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("08.06.2016_07.07.2016_exampleUser");
```

If you found Month's cache you can iterate the get the Week's cache from it or you have to get the week's cache from Database.

Comment: Could you please provide an example how can I declare/inject custom cache manager? Right now I use Spring Boot where default cache manager is configured automatically

Comment: You can just do `@Autowired` CacheManager cacheManager in your `@Service` class